# Lower regularity version of Moser's theorem on volume elements

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

A theorem of Moser, published in "On the Volume Elements of a Manifold" (Transactions of the Americal Mathematical Society 120, 1965; [doi: 10.1090/S0002-9947-1965-0182927-5](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1965-0182927-5), [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1994022)), shows that if a $C^\infty$ compact manifold $M$ has two $C^\infty$ volume forms $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ with the same total mass, then there is a diffeomorphism of $M$ sending one to the other.

I am interested in what is known if the manifold and volume forms have lower regularity (in particular, I really want to know about the $C^{1+\alpha}$ case.

Thanks for any reference suggestions.

EDITED:
So having had an answer from Robert Bryant, I realized I should have been more precise about the specific question(s) that I was asking:

> If $M$ is a $C^{1+\alpha}$ manifold and $\omega_i$, $i=1,2$ are two $C^\alpha$
> volume forms with the same mass, does there exist a $C^{1+\alpha}$ diffeomorphism sending one the other?

The comment below from AlvarezPaiva suggests the answer to the above might be yes, but the context there appears to be bounded subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

> If $M$ is a $C^{1}$ manifold and $\omega_i$, $i=1,2$ are two continuous
> volume forms with the same mass, does there exist a $C^1$ diffeomorphism sending one to the other?

Final full disclosure in case this drastically simplifies things: my manifold is topologically a two-dimensional torus.

Comment: I haven't looked at this in a long time, but I remember  that Dacorogna and Moser considered lowering the regularity hypothesis in Moser's theorem. Here is the reference: Dacorogna B. and Moser J., On a partial differential equation involving the Jacobian determinant, Ann. Inst.
H. Poincare Anal. Non Lineaire, 7 (1990), 1-26

Comment: Thanks again @alvarezpaiva: I have just had a brief look at the paper, but this seems as though it will answer my question (when I understand the paper). If you make this an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva I added a link to a free copy of the paper by Dacorogna and Moser in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If $M$ is a $C^{1}$ manifold and $\omega_i$, $i=1,2$ are two continuous
> volume forms with the same mass, does there exist a $C^1$ diffeomorphism sending one to the other?

**The answer is no.** The equivalent problem is: given a positive and continuous function $g$, can we find a diffeomorphism with the Jacobian equal to $g$, $\det Df=g$? A counterexample is Theorem 1.2  in [1].

> If $M$ is a $C^{1,\alpha}$ manifold and $\omega_i$, $i=1,2$ are two $C^\alpha$
> volume forms with the same mass, does there exist a $C^{1,\alpha}$ diffeomorphism sending one the other?

**The answer is yes, at least locally** (see also a comment of  alvarezpaiva). Whether the result has a global version on manifolds, I do not know. This is Theorem 1 in [3]. For a comprehensive treatment of related results, see [2].

> **Theorem.** *Let $k\geq 0$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$. If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is abounded domain with $C^{k+3,\alpha}$
>   boundary and $\omega\in C^{k,\alpha}$ is a volume form such that
>   $\int_\Omega\omega=|\Omega|$, then there is a diffeomorphism
>   $\varphi:\Omega\to\Omega$ that is identity on the boundary,
>   $\varphi,\varphi^{-1}\in C^{k+1,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ and such that
>   $\varphi^*\omega=dx_1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx_n$.*

[1] **D. Burago, B. Kleiner,** [Separated nets in Euclidean space and Jacobians of bi-Lipschitz maps](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs000390050056).
*Geom. Funct. Anal.* 8 (1998), 273–282. 
([MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=RT&pg7=JOUR&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=burago%20and%20kleiner&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=1616135).)

[2] **G. Csató, B. Dacorogna, O. Kneuss,** [The pullback equation for differential forms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-8176-8313-9). Progress in Nonlinear Differential Equations and their Applications, 83. Birkhäuser/Springer, New York, 2012. 
([MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2883631%0A).)

[3] **B. Dacorogna, J. Moser,** 
[On a partial differential equation involving the Jacobian determinant](http://caa.epfl.ch/publications/22-Dacorogna-Moser1990.pdf). 
*Ann. Inst. H. Poincaré Anal. Non Linéaire* 7 (1990),  1–26. 
([MathSciNet review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=RT&pg7=JOUR&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=dacorogna%20and%20moser&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq).)

Answer (score 6):

I think that the usual proof goes through in this case, although, obviously, you don't get a diffeomorphism (i.e., $C^\infty$ invertible map) identifying the two volume forms, just a $C^{1+\alpha}$ map with a $C^{1+\alpha}$ inverse.

Look at the steps:  First, you need to find an $(n-1)$-form $\phi$ such that $\omega_2-\omega_1 = \mathrm{d}\phi$, and you should make sure that it is at least $C^{1+\alpha}$.  To do this, you note that $\omega_2-\omega_1$ is zero in deRham cohomology (this is the 'equal mass' hypothesis; of course, you need to assume that $M$ is connected for this to work, but that's part of the hypothesis anyway), and then use, say, a Green's operator (which, at least, doesn't *decrease regularity*) for some smooth metric to write
$$
\omega_2-\omega_1 = \mathrm{d}\left(G(\omega_2{-}\omega_1)\right),
$$
then take $\phi =  G(\omega_2{-}\omega_1)$.  Second, on $M\times [0,1]$ (with $t$ as the coordinate on the second factor), consider the $n$-form (which is $C^{1+\alpha}$)
$$
\omega = (1{-}t)\,\omega_1 + t\,\omega_2 + \mathrm{d}t\wedge\phi.
$$
This form satisfies $\mathrm{d}\omega = 0$ by construction, and it is never vanishing since $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ determine the same orientation of $M$.  Third, there is a unique vector field $X$ on $M\times[0,1]$ that satisfies 
$$
\iota_X\left(\mathrm{d}t\wedge\omega\right) = \omega,
$$
where $\iota_X$ means interior product with $X$.  This vector field satisfies $\mathrm{d}t(X) \equiv 1$, so we can look at the time $1$ flow of this vector field, which carries $M\times\{0\}$ to $M\times\{1\}$.  Fourth, since $\omega$ is closed and since $\iota_X(\omega) = 0$, it follows from Cartan's formula that the Lie derivative of $\omega$ with respect to $X$ is zero, i.e., that the flow of $X$ preserves $\omega$.

But now, the time $1$ flow of $X$ (which is a $C^{1+\alpha}$ vector field) is then a $C^{1+\alpha}$ map (with $C^{1+\alpha}$ inverse) from $M$ to $M$ that pulls back $\omega_2$ to $\omega_1$.  This is because $\omega$ pulls back to $M\times\{0\}$ to be $\omega_1$ and it pulls back to $M\times\{1\}$ to be $\omega_2$.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Sorry - this is far from what I know about - it will take me some time to process this. May I ask slightly more about this (apologies for not managing to express this fully the first time around): If the manifold is $C^{1+\alpha}$ and the volume forms are just $C^\alpha$, can you still get a $C^{1+\alpha}$ diffeomorphism? Does this break down at $\alpha=0$?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas:  Unfortunately, I don't know the answer in your more general case. Probably, though, if you have the $\omega_i$ being $C^\alpha$, you can get $\phi$ (and hence $X$) to be $C^\alpha$ in the above argument.  However, whether the flow of $X$ will then be $C^{1+\alpha}$ is another question.  I suspect that it is not, and that the proof with optimum regularity that you want may need to be done by some other means, so probably checking alvarezpaiva's suggested reference is better than what I was suggesting.

Comment: I suspect Robert is correct about the regularity. When you integrate a flow, you gain a derivative in the time direction only and not in any transverse ("spatial") directions. This can be seen from the proof of the existence and uniqueness of parameterized ODE's.

Comment: If you can somehow make the flow also satisfy either a parabolic PDE or a transverse elliptic PDE, then you would achieve the regularity you want.

Comment: @DeaneYang Because of your comments you might find my answer interesting.

Comment: @RobertBryant Because of your answer you might find mine interesting.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz:  Thanks for the notice and the pointer to the references for this question.  While I was sure that this kind of thing had to be known, it's not the kind of question I normally think about, so I didn't know the right references.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz The remark right before Section 2.4 of [2] says that their method doesn't give a $C^{1,\alpha}$ diffeomorphism that is identity *on a neighborhood* of $\partial\Omega$. Can this be fixed by a pasting argument (say first shrink $\Omega$ along its collar neighborhood)? If so, then the local result can be globalized by a ($C^{1,\alpha}$) partition of unity argument that changes the volume form in a coordinate chart, one at a time.

Comment: @FanZheng I am leaving tomorrow and I will be away for several weeks so I will not have a chance to look at your question. Sorry.